# Sencha Touch 2.0 Manifest Query String

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm setting my app up to run offline and I have hit a brick wall. All of my files are being cached but I noticed in the Safari console that the app is adding a query sting to the filename so the correct file is not loaded. In Safari the link looks like this

```
http://serverpath/resources/data/data.json?_dc=1337372230084&node=root&page=1&start=0&limit=25
```

Is there any way to prevent the query string from being added? My data store code is below.

```
Ext.define('App.store.Sections', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

    requires: [
        'App.model.Sections'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,

        model: 'App.model.Sections',

        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'resources/data/data.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'items'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Ext.Ajax.setDisableCaching](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-setDisableCaching).

Be careful of the double negation: it has to be set to false in your case : you don't want to use the disable caching system.

Comment: I changed my data store to the following but it still isn't working. All of the ?dc= stuff is preventing the app from running off line. Am I totally missing something?     
        
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
     disableCaching:false,
            url: 'resources/data/data.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'items'
            }

Comment: I also added the following bit to the top of my app.js but it didn't work either.                             Ext.Loader.setConfig({
enabled: true,
disableCaching:false
});

Comment: Try Ext.Ajax.setDisableCaching(false); at the top of your app